# Работа с большим количеством записей в сессии

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Каким образом правильно работать с большим количеством записей с SQLAlchemy?

У меня есть две таблички. В первой 5 миллионов записей вида: `question_id`, `view_count`, `counted`. Во второй таблице находятся сумма `view_count` для каждого уникального `question_id`. Если мы учли запись из первой таблицы во второй, `counted` выставляется в истину.

Сейчас это выглядет так:

```
def update_most_viewed():
    query = QuestionViewHistory.query.filter_by(counted=False).distinct()
    question_count = query.count()
    frame_size = 1000
    counter = 0

    while counter <= question_count:
        all_questions = query.offset(counter*frame_size).limit(frame_size).all()
        counter = counter + frame_size

        for question in all_questions:
            most_viewed_question = MostViewedQuestion.query.filter_by(question_id=question.question_id).first()

            if most_viewed_question is None:
                most_viewed_question = MostViewedQuestion(question.question_id, question.view_count)
                db.session.add(most_viewed_question)
            else:
                most_viewed_question.view_count += question.view_count

            question.counted = True

        db.session.commit()
```

Вызываю функцию из консоли. Инициализация:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Проблема в том, что с каждым проходом время растет экспоненциально: после пятого прохода все зависает. Если запустить программу повторно, все повторяется один в один.

На сколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что при каждом вызове `commit`, SQLAlchemy обновляет все атрибуты всех объектов в сессии, но способа как это поправить, к сожалению, не нашел.

**Обновление**

Классы моделей, которые фигурируют в запросе.

```
class MostViewedQuestion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'most_viewed_question'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    view_count = db.Column(db.Integer)    
    is_associated = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    can_be_associated = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    title = db.Column(db.String(500))
    body = db.Column(db.String(30000))
    tags = db.Column(db.String(500))   
    last_update_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)  

    def __init__(self, question_id, view_count, is_associated=False):
        self.question_id = question_id
        self.view_count = view_count
        self.is_associated = is_associated
        self.can_be_associated = True
        self.last_update_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MostViewedQuestion %s>' % str(self.id)        

class QuestionViewHistory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'question_view_history'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    view_count = db.Column(db.Integer)       
    view_date = db.Column(db.DateTime) 
    counted = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, question_id, view_count, view_date):
        self.question_id = question_id
        self.view_count = view_count
        self.view_date = view_date
        self.counted = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<QuestionViewHistory %s>' % str(self.id)
```

Код всего проекта доступен на [GitHub](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools), все модели находятся в файле [models.py](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/blob/master/server_app/models.py), функция `update_most_viewed` в файле [database.py](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/blob/master/server_app/database.py). В папке [cvs_data_ru](https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools/tree/master/server_app/csv_data_ru) данные для тестов.

Comment: Для массовых вставок/обновлений есть набор методов `bulk_...`. Например, [bulk_save_objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects). С этим методом сохранение будет выглядеть как-то так: `db.session.bulk_save_objects([most_viewed_q1, most_viewed_q2, most_viewed_q3 ... most_viewed_qn])` + `commit`.

Comment: @m9_psy К сожалению, не помогает, пробовал. Более того, такое ощущение, что проблема не во вставке, а в выборке. Предварительно я заполняю первую таблицу 5 млн записями примерно таким же образом, но без операций чтения из базы (собираю сессию по 100К записей и делаю `commit`). Все проходит очень быстро.

Comment: @m9_psy Видимо, нашел решение: создаю две сессии, одну на запись, другую на чтение (правда, это, видимо, не важно), затем читаю не объекты из первой таблички, а только `id`, `question_id`, `view_count`. Во второй записываю изменению в обоих табличках и отправляю в базу. То есть при отправке данных ORM отслеживать нечего, по сути. Погоняю тесты еще. Если все хорошо, опубликую ответ.

Comment: Еще помогли бы сами модели и какой-нибудь код, чтобы заполнить таблицы в БД случайными данными. Минимальный пример, короче. А то гипотез может быть много. Вот, например, еще гипотеза - использовать [update + insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#insert-updates-deletes) методы, т.е. всю тяжелую работу перенести в базу и тем самым удалить циклы в питоновском коде, но т.к. мне лень самому придумывать модели и фикстуры, то гипотезу проверить не удается - не превращать же вопрос в ярмарку домыслов?

Comment: Абсолютно согласен с @m9_psy. Лучше делать это на стороне RDBMS вместо циклов...

Comment: если у вас миллион вопросов, то квадратичный алгоритм это ~10¹² операций, что долгое время в Питоне займет даже если не пользоваться никакой базой данных (всё в предположении O(1) операций внутри циклов). Попробуйте изменить алгоритм, чтобы лучше временна́я сложность была. В частности, отгрузка в базу данных работы может помочь так как некоторые базы данных при умеренно больших размерах могут даже самостоятельно индексы строить для ускорения запросов и другие улучшения (разумное big O). Посмотрите, какой SQL выполняется `logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)`

Comment: @m9_psy  Использование функции update ничего не дало, к сожалению.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит начать с того, как делать не нужно. Например, не нужно перебирать объекты в базе по-одному:

```
for question in all_questions:
    most_viewed_question = MostViewedQuestion.query.filter_by(question_id=question.question_id).first()
```

этот цикл - совсем нет-нет-нет. Такого поведения нужно избегать любой ценой - НАМНОГО лучше запросить сразу миллион строк, чем миллион раз по одной строке. Если нужно получить все объекты `MostViewedQuestion`, то лучше это сделать одним запросом:

```
most_viewed_questions = MostViewedQuestion.query.filter_by(question_id.in_=questions)
```

В таком случае отпадает нужда и во внешнем цикле `while`, потому что по-прежнему, лучше запросить один раз миллион, чем тысячу раз по тысяче. После такого запроса БД вернет те `most_viewed_questions`, для которых есть соответствующая запись. Встает вопрос: что делать с теми, у которых такой записи нет? Такие запросы выполняются в БД очень часто и часто их называют `UPSERT` (`UPDATE` + `INSERT`) - нужно одновременно и обновить какую-то запись, а если ее нет, то создать ее. Все, что нужно - это выполнить вот этот вот `upsert` средствами `sqlalchemy`. Состоять запрос будет из двух подзапросов - один обновит существующие записи (`update`), другой создаст новые (`insert`).

`UPDATE` в целом довольно прямолинейный:

```
from sqlalchemy import not_, select, exists

update_query = MostViewedQuestion.__table__.update().values(
            view_count=MostViewedQuestion.view_count + QuestionViewHistory.view_count
        ).where(and_(
                     MostViewedQuestion.question_id == QuestionViewHistory.question_id,
                     QuestionViewHistory.counted == True
        ))
```

Оно генерирует вот такой SQL:

```
UPDATE most_viewed_question SET view_count=(most_viewed_question.view_count + question_view_history.view_count) 
FROM question_view_history 
WHERE most_viewed_question.question_id = question_view_history.question_id
AND question_view_history.counted = true
```

Я использовал запись `MostViewedQuestion.__table__`, потому что мои модели наследуются от `declarative_base()`, а методы `update()`, `delete()`, `insert()` есть у класса `Table`(у `Base` их нет). Для `declarative_base` сама таблица находится в поле `__table__`.

`INSERT` немного более запутанный, но самая мякотка - `from_select()`, который генерирует `INSERT ... FROM SELECT`:

```
insert_query = MostViewedQuestion.__table__.insert().\
            from_select([MostViewedQuestion.question_id, MostViewedQuestion.view_count],
                     select([QuestionViewHistory.question_id, QuestionViewHistory.view_count]).
                     where(and_(not_(exists([MostViewedQuestion.question_id]).where(MostViewedQuestion.question_id == QuestionViewHistory.question_id)
                      ),  # WHERE ... AND ...
                            QuestionViewHistory.counted == True))
                      )

SESSION.execute(update_query)
SESSION.execute(insert_query)
SESSION.commit()
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO most_viewed_question (question_id, view_count) 
    SELECT question_view_history.question_id, question_view_history.view_count 
    FROM question_view_history 
    WHERE NOT (EXISTS (
        SELECT most_viewed_question.question_id 
        FROM most_viewed_question 
        WHERE most_viewed_question.question_id = question_view_history.question_id)) 
        AND question_view_history.counted = true
```

Я бы не сказал, что данный запрос - образец скорости, но самое главное в этих запросах - так это то, что работает БД. Питонский код в это время просто ждет ответа от БД и нам вообще не надо думать об оптимизации питоновского кода. Не нужно ломать голову об устройстве `SQLAlchemy`. Зато стоит подумать об оптимизации SQL, но с этим несколько легче, потому что `UPSERT` - операция типичная и по ней много всего написано. Но это не повод расслабляться, потому что при обновлении/вставке большого количества записей в БД есть свои нюансы (например, раздувание таблиц (table bloating) или индексы/триггеры, которые тормозят процесс и перед массовой вставкой их выключают).

Comment: Общую идею понял, огромное спасибо! Буду разбираться, но пока урежу данные и оставлю предыдущую версию. Приведенный вами пример немного не верно работает в моем случае так как: 1) вставка не обрабатывает одинаковые записи в первой таблице и вставляет все во вторую, 2) как я понял, запрос на обновление суммирует только записи таблицы, а не для всех, 3) поскольку обновление и вставка происходят не одновременно невозможно отследить, что учтено (и выставить `counted=True`, а что нет), а в случае когда обновляться надо не по всей первой табличке, запрос не отработает.

Comment: Как я понял, люди пишут расширения по принципу `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Но, опять же, надо разбираться, каким образом обновлять первую таблицу при вставке во вторую.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, у вас в примере обновляются все записи из `QuestionViewHistory` - безо всяких условий. Ну и запросы эталонно простые, да. Если запросы усложняться и условия появятся - проблемы также никакой нет - можно сначала запросить нужные id для изменения/вставки - а потом их изменить. В PostgreSQL даже есть укороченная инструкция [RETURNING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html), которая вернет все вставленные или измененные столбцы - удобная вещь. Также стоит опасаться текстовых модификаций, таких как ON DUPLICATE. В каких-то базах он есть - в каких-то нет.

Comment: При выборке `QuestionViewHistory` я фильтрую по  `counted=False` – `QuestionViewHistory.query.filter_by(counted=False)`. Надо исследовать, как можно улучшить работу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, еще, кстати, если сырые insert(), update() не кажутся подходящими остается выход - добавлять или изменять модели можно из другого потока. В вашем коде питон большую часть простаивает - ждет ответа БД, ждет пересылки данных (тоже не бесплатно), поэтому можно ждать в параллельном потоке. Также в своем app.config можно попробовать поставить `SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False` - также вроде должно немного помочь. Но основное правило все-таки не запрашивать объекты по-одному или по тысяче.

Comment: Ваш ответ, конечно же правильны! Спасибо! Единственное, на до конца понял принцип работы запроса на обновление. Представим, что у нас 100 записей с одинаковым вопросом. Как я понимаю, запрос прибавит к каждому значению лишь одно из других, а не все. Подскажите, где я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2):

Что получилось в результате:

```
def update_most_viewed():
    reader_session = db_session()
    question_count = reader_session.query(func.count(QuestionViewHistory.id)).filter_by(counted=False).scalar()
    query = reader_session.query(QuestionViewHistory.id, QuestionViewHistory.question_id, QuestionViewHistory.view_count).filter_by(counted=False)
    frame_size = 1000
    progress_index = 0
    counter = 0

    print "Questions to update: %s, frame size: %s" % (question_count, frame_size) 

    while counter <= question_count:
        all_questions = query.offset(0).limit(frame_size).all()
        counter = counter + frame_size

        wiriter_session = db_session()
        for question in all_questions:
            record_id, question_id, view_count = question
            most_viewed_question = wiriter_session.query(MostViewedQuestion).filter_by(question_id=question_id).first()
            if most_viewed_question is None:
                most_viewed_question = MostViewedQuestion(question_id, view_count)
                wiriter_session.add(most_viewed_question)
            else:
                most_viewed_question.view_count += view_count

            qh = wiriter_session.query(QuestionViewHistory).filter_by(id=record_id).first()
            qh.counted = True
            wiriter_session.add(qh)

            print_progress_bar(progress_index, question_count, prefix = 'Progress:', suffix = 'Complete')
            progress_index +=1

        wiriter_session.commit()
        wiriter_session.close()

    print "All questions were counted"
```

#### В чем отличие от исходного варианта

Если верить документации SQLAlchemy, ORM отслеживает все объекты находящиеся в сессии, для того, чтобы гарантировать их актуальность относительно данных в базе. Это приводит к тому, что после каждого вызова `commit`, ORM отмечает объекты сессии как требующие обновления, что приводит к большой нагрузке на БД. С ростом количества объектов в сессии растет и время их обновления. Решение сводится к тому, чтобы держать в сессии как можно меньше объектов.

1. Я добавил две сессии: `reader_session` и `wiriter_session`, которые, судя по [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631773/6), на самом деле являются одной и той же сессией.
2. Далее (главный трюк) при обращении к базе я запрашиваю не весь объект целиком, а только нужную информацию (`id`, `question_id`, `view_count`), количество объектов считаю через функцию `func.count(QuestionViewHistory.id)`. В результате, как я понимаю, у меня нет объектов в сессии для отслеживания.
3. Все операции на запись добавляю в `wiriter_session`.

Сейчас скорость выполнения функции не зависит от количества данных (от номера прохода), все же остается низкой. Буду думать над улучшением алгоритма.

П.С. Как я понимаю, в исходном коде была допущена ошибка в работе с «окном»: в цикле мы меняем таблицу (обновляем `counted`), а потом сдвигаем окно, чем пропускаем часть записей. Как я понимаю, надо все время начинать с нулевой позиции. То есть:

```
 all_questions = query.offset(0).limit(frame_size).all()
```