# Как правильно обращаться к объекту сессии?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Есть код:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)  


def make_db_session(engine):
    return scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
        autoflush=True,
        bind=engine))    

def make_db_engine():
    return create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], convert_unicode=True)

engine = make_db_engine()
db_session = make_db_session(engine)
```

Далее, я вижу несколько примеров обращения к сессии.

1. Первый вариант

   ```
   db.session.some_action()
   ```
2. Второй вариант

   ```
   db_session.some_action()
   ```
3. Третий вариант

   ```
   session = db_session()
   session.some_action()
   ```

В чем их различия? Какой способ является более верным?

П.С. Еще интересно то, что если делать выборку следующим образом

```
model = SomeModel.query.filter(some_filter).first()
model.field = new_value
```

То сохранять необходимо как

```
db.session.commit()
```

То есть, создается впечатление, что по умолчанию используется сессия `db.session`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно начать с отличий:

Функция `make_db_session` возвращает объект типа `ScopedSession` ([`scoped_session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session) - это класс такой, который зачем-то назвали как функцию). `scoped_session` - обычная такая сессия, но помимо бла-бла-бла про потоки, основное ее отличие, видимое пользователям, в следующем:

```
# Обычные сессии

Session = sessionmaker(__config_here__)

session_1 = Session()
session_2 = Session()

my_db_entry = Entry(slug='Yolo')
session_1.add(my_db_entry)  # На этом моменте my_db_entry привязан в первой сессии
session_2.add(my_db_entry)
```

`# На этом моменте возникнет` [`исключение`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#thread-local-scope)

То есть добавить один и тот же объект с разных сессий не выйдет.

ScopedSession - это на самом деле одна и та же сессия всегда (в данном потоке, пояснения ниже). Т.е.

```
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
print(type(session_factory))
>>> <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker'>

session_registry = ScopedSession(session_factory)
print(type(session_registry))
>>> <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session'>
```

При вызове `session_registry()` (`__call__`) без параметров возвращается то, что лежит в регистре. Регистр - экземпляр класса `ThreadLocalRegistry`. То, что туда однажды положили, изменить нельзя (На самом деле я не уверен - возможно, в методе баг или лишний код - он как-то странно написан - смотри с 64 строки в `sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py`). Также, если вызовете `session_registry()` из другого потока - то в нем уже [будет другая сессия](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#thread-local-scope), созданная специально для него. То есть "thread-local" в документации означает, что для каждого потока своя сессия, а не то, что сессии как-то хитро синхронизируются, ставят локи и т.д. Это достигается использованием [threading.local()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.local) в регистре.

```
session_1 = session_registry()
session_2 = session_registry()
print(type(session1), type(session_2))
>>> <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>
session_1 is session_2
>>> True
```

это одна и та же сессия. Это означает, например, что регистр с сессией можно сделать глобальным. Также [необязательно создавать объекты класса `Session`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#implicit-method-access) (`session_1` и `session-2`) - так как сессия одна вполне зайдет `session_registry.query(MyClass).all()`

Также в том же разделе есть [наглядная диаграмма](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications), показывающая когда нужно создавать регистр, когда нужно создавать и закрывать сессию.

Что использовать "правильнее" сказать сложно, но я бы сказал, что `scoped_session`, а не создавать свою гольную `Session(...)`, потому что сессии не потоко-безопасны и придется создавать на каждый поток новую сессию, либо синхронизироваться как-то.

Чтобы использовать свою сессию, а не предоставленную `flask-sqlalchemy`, Есть несколько путей:

вызывать `query` на нужной сессии:

```
session.query(MyObject.prop, AnotherOne.prop2).filter(blah-blah)
```

Также вы можете на свои модели установить "сессию по умолчанию". У каждой модели может быть поле `query`, куда можно присунуть "запросник" (на этом моменте все начинает быть настолько запутанно, что не поддается объяснению). Примерно [как-то так](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html?highlight=scoped_session#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session.query_property). Также есть [небольшое обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350807/whats-the-difference-between-model-query-and-session-querymodel-in-sqlalchemy) разницы между этими подходами на ENSO.

Update:

Возвращаясь к тому, какой вариант "верный", скажу, что второй и третий равнозначны, но использовать стоит третий, чтобы точно знать, что используется объект Session, а не какой-то иной. Но тогда зачем использовать `flask-SQLAlchemy`? Выходит, что многое из того, что эта библиотека прячет от пользователя (настройки сессии, обратные вызовы типа `before_rollback`, `after_commit`, `after_flush` и т.д. навешаны на библиотечную сессию. Также используется свой особенный "запросник" - класс `orm.Query` со всякими плюшками, вроде автоматической отправки 404, если нет объекта в БД. Логи всякие, встроенная пагинация (постраничные запросы в БД).

Также сессия по умолчанию - `db.session` - во время создания моделей именно она записывается в свойство `query`. Вы можете убедиться в этом, отыскав класс `SQLAlchemy` в пакете, в нем метод `__init__`, а в нем уже строчку, в которой инициализируется поле `Model` (которое затем используется как базовый класс). Это поле инициализируется результатом функции `make_declarative_base` и вот как эта функция выглядит (довольно простая):

```
def make_declarative_base(self, metadata=None):
    """Creates the declarative base."""
    base = declarative_base(cls=Model, name='Model',
                            metadata=metadata,
                            metaclass=_BoundDeclarativeMeta)
    base.query = _QueryProperty(self)
    return base
```

Как видно, заветный `query` инициализируется своим классом, который создается именно с сессией flask-SQLAlchemy, а не какой-нибудь иной. Т.о. сессия по умолчанию была явно объявлена в базовом классе `db.Model`. Можно поменять ее, перезаписав `query` на тот, что нужен.

Comment: Как я понимаю, все–таки правильно будет использовать именно созданной через `scoped_session` (то есть третий вариант)? Сейчас в классах моделей (наследую от `db.Model`) я никак не объявляю поле `query`, получается, используется какая-то другая сессия по умолчанию?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, обновил ответ.