# Является ли в sqlalchemy метод сессии merge эквивалентом add+commit?

Tags: python, база-данных, orm, sqlalchemy

Читаю документацию по sqlalchemy, но некоторые нюансы от меня ускользают.

Является ли код

```
session.add(item)
session.commit()
```

эквивалентом кода

```
session.merge(item)
```

?

Если нет - то в чём разница?
Если да - то могу ли я вместо большого числа merge использовать аналогичное число add, а потом один общий commit? Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае реально будет выполнен один sql-запрос вместо множества и это даст экономию времени выполнения?

Если да - то после какого числа add стоит делать коммит?

Дело в том, что я сейчас поддерживаю чужой код. В нём в циклах создаются десятки тысяч новых item, которые нужно добавить (или обновить, если уже существуют строки с тем же первичным ключом) в базу, и скрипт отрабатывает два-три часа. Могу ли я ожидать ускорения после замены merge на add+commit? Не может ли это привести к неожиданным проблемам?

База данных на PostgreSQL, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Связанный вопрос про большое количество объектов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631587/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: По поводу вопроса: не является, или является с очень большой натяжкой - merge() делает больше, чем просто добавляет, обновляет объект. Собственно, в [документации](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.merge) написано, что конкретно метод делает. Есть еще нечитабельный параграф про то, [зачем этот merge нужен](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merge-tips) - и он не зря расположен в разделе Session State Management, то есть не совсем предназначен для добавления/обновления данных в БД.